# getElementsByTagName doesn't work in PHP

Tags: php

I have this HTML Code:

```
<div id="sd_rce">
  <br>
  <h2>The Content I want</h2>
</div>
```

And I want to get "The Content I want" with PHP. I tried this

```
    $html = //LookAbove;
    $DOM = new DOMDocument;
    $DOM->loadHTML($html);

   $items = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('h2');

   for ($i = 0; $i < $items->length; $i++)
        echo $items->item($i)->nodeValue . "<br/>";
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong ? A white site is all what I get.

Comment: A white screen means you must turn on error reporting, as you have a fatal PHP error.  `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`  _Always_ develop with error reporting turned on.

Comment: I put this in my code then my variable was shown, but now error ?

Comment: Is DOMDocument class is available?check in php.ini , or if(class_exists("DOMDocument")){//.....}else{echo "class is not available";}

Comment: There's nothing syntactically wrong with your code. Are you sure php-xml is available? As Michael said, turn on error reporting to find out what fatal error is being thrown.

Comment: Found it, my original code included characters like ä,ö,ü.

Comment: @Sebastian see the answer of Dima Goltsman, give the right encoding with it is the key ;)

Answer (score 2):

try

```
$DOM = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'iso-8859-1');
```

Comment: +1 but please explain why so viewers will know what it does. Btw always give the encoding when you initialize the `DOMDoucment` so it will work on every server even when the default is different then your encoding.

Comment: its the default example here http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.construct.php , usualy this is the best way to do it

Answer (score 0):

Giving encoding options is good idea always, I believe.

However for the situation posted here, I suspect if you are dealing with text result from htmlspecialchars().

In web browser, you will see "<" char, but actually it might be "<", then PHP DOM could not parse whole text correctly.